# Bootstrap form-group elements spacing

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm trying to reduce the gap between the form-group's checkbox and textbox. I have already tried the "text-right" but still not able to shrink the gap very close so that it becomes next to each other.

[image]

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-2 text-right">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label><input type="checkbox"> Click to Check</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter text">
        </div>
    </div>

<form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic overview of Bootstrap is very important for this. col-xs-2 is getting the horizontal space of 1/12, and that's going to be fix untill you change the main .css files of bootstrap. But, that is not recommended.

Solution: Remove the text-right.

Answer (score 2):

Your input elements have been placed into adjacent column divs using `class="col-xs-2"`. When using a bootstrap column layout, the width of the columns is flexible, and changes with the size of the window. This means that the observed distance between the input elements will be different for each user of your site.

If you want to control the distance between the input elements, it will be necessary to put them inside the same column, or abandon a column layout altogether.

Unless using a bootstrap [inline-form](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline), the input element will be styled to have `width: 100%`. This makes it take up the whole column, so it will appear on a new line. To prevent this, you will need to override the `width` style of the input element.

Comment: Thanks for the response starchild, I have already tried placing them inside the single column layout but the textbox goes to the next row instead of staying with the checkbox row.